# An "Error creating bean with name 'functionBindingRegistrar'" exception every time I start my application

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-function

I have a normal spring cloud stream application that simple reads data from Kafka topic and produces messages to another Kafka topic, please find below the configurations:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.6</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<properties>
    <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
    <spring-boot-maven-plugin.version>2.3.0.RELEASE</spring-boot-maven-plugin.version>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And the following application.proeprties

```
#Kafka Configurations
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.auto.offset.reset=latest

spring.cloud.function.definition=merchantCredentials;validatedProducts;validateImages;retryUnprocessedItems
#Input topics
#Merchants
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.merchantCredentials-in-0.destination=mis.merchantCtpCredentials
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.merchantCredentials-in-0.consumer.ack-mode=manual_immediate
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.merchantCredentials-in-0.contentType=application/json
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.merchantCredentials-in-0.consumer.header-mode=headers
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.merchantCredentials-in-0.consumer.partitioned=true
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.merchantCredentials-in-0.consumer.max-attempts=1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.merchantCredentials-in-0.group=tuevGroup

#kfc.notifications.product
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.validatedProducts-in-0.destination=kfc.notifications.product
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.validatedProducts-in-0.consumer.ack-mode=manual_immediate
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.validatedProducts-in-0.contentType=application/json
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.validatedProducts-in-0.consumer.header-mode=headers
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.validatedProducts-in-0.consumer.concurrency=5
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.validatedProducts-in-0.consumer.partitioned=true
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.validatedProducts-in-0.consumer.max-attempts=1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.validatedProducts-in-0.group=tuevGroup

#marketplace.products
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.validateImages-in-0.destination=marketplace.products
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.validateImages-in-0.consumer.ack-mode=manual_immediate
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.validateImages-in-0.contentType=application/json
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.validateImages-in-0.consumer.header-mode=headers
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.validateImages-in-0.consumer.partitioned=true
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.validateImages-in-0.consumer.max-attempts=1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.validateImages-in-0.group=tuevGroup

#Output topics
#productValidated
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.validatedProducts-out-0.destination=marketplace.validated.products
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.validatedProducts-out-0.contentType=application/json
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.validatedProducts-out-0.producer.partition-count=10
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.validatedProducts-out-0.producer.header-mode=headers

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.retryUnprocessedItems-out-0.destination=marketplace.validated.products
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.retryUnprocessedItems-out-0.contentType=application/json
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.retryUnprocessedItems-out-0.producer.partition-count=10
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.retryUnprocessedItems-out-0.producer.header-mode=headers
spring.cloud.stream.poller.cron=0 0/10 * * * *
spring.cloud.stream.poller.initial-delay=10000
```

And below is the signature of all defined spring cloud functions

```
@Bean
public Consumer<Flux<Message<JsonNode>>> merchantCredentials() {

@Bean
public Function<Message<NotificationMessage>, Message<ProductValidatedEvent>> validatedProducts() {

@Bean
public Consumer<Message<ProductImportMessage>> validateImages() {

@PollableBean
@SchedulerLock(name = "retryProcess_scheduledTask", lockAtMostFor = "${retry.job.lock.atMost}", lockAtLeastFor = "${retry.job.lock.atLeast}")
public Supplier<Flux<Message<ProductValidatedEvent>>> retryUnprocessedItems() {
```

Everything works fine, and the application starts and functions as it should, however, in the logs I encounter this exception multiple times, specially during the start up phase of the application

```
org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'functionBindingRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/stream/function/FunctionConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type must be one of Supplier, Function or Consumer
```

I have double checked all configurations and I still have no clue how can I prevent this issue from happening. Why this exception is happening? is it ignorable ?

**UPDATE 1**:

I have tracked the bug to this function in spring framework, *FunctionTypeUtils*:

```
    public static Type discoverFunctionTypeFromClass(Class<?> functionalClass) {
    Assert.isTrue(isFunctional(functionalClass), "Type must be one of Supplier, Function or Consumer");
```

this function gets called by this function in *FunctionConfiguration*:

```
private String[] filterEligibleFunctionDefinitions() {
...
                for (int i = 0; i < functionNames.length && eligibleDefinition; i++) {
                    String functionName = functionNames[i];
                    if (this.applicationContext.containsBean(functionName)) {
```

And when I added debug points to this one, as well as the previous one I got the following output

```
functionName: merchantCredentials
functionalClass: com.rewedigital.services.tuev.marketplace.merchant.flow.MerchantFlowManger$$Lambda$1323/0x00000008008fc040
functionName: validatedProducts
functionalClass: com.rewedigital.services.tuev.marketplace.validator.listener.ProductChangedListener$$Lambda$1331/0x00000008008fa040
functionName: validateImages
functionalClass: com.rewedigital.services.tuev.marketplace.sieve.listener.ProductImagesListener$$Lambda$1324/0x00000008008fc440
functionName: retryUnprocessedItems
functionalClass: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.NullBean
```

Showing that the retryUnprocessedItems is the culprit, not sure why though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, it turned out that the problem is mainly with the `@SchedulerLock` annotation.

I observed that this issue happens while then shedLock table has lock added on the method, and hence it was preventing the `FunctionBeanRegistrar` from adding the method, and so the exception.

Of course this means on the other hand that the annotation is now deemed not usable because what `@PollableBean` annotation really runs is not the function itself, but rather the Supplier lambda expression returned by the function, practically rendering the `ShedLock` useless.

Once I remove the annotation, all the exceptions are gone and the sun shines again, birds sing, etc etc..

The next question to answer would be how to use rollable bean in a distributed manner but that is out of the scope of this question